# c# подставлять элементы массива

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Народ подскажите как мне реализовать следующее, 
есть разрешение в конце имени файла "1024x768", "1280x1024" их всего 4.
мне нужно чтобы проверялось имя файла с помощью EndsWith(). Чтобы в цикле 
в EndsWith() подставлялись элемента из массива ( "1024x768", "1280x1024", "1600x900", "1920x1080") и при совпадении условия выполнял действия, подскажите, как мне в цикле подставлять каждый элемент из массива и проверять на условие в c# новичок....

Comment: что в цикле должно происходить ?

Comment: Добавьте код в котором вы получаете имя файла и образцы имен файлов, которые нужно проверять.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте массив:

```
string[] dims = { "1024x768", "1280x1024", "1600x900", "1920x1080" };
```

и проверяйте в цикле:

```
string filename = ...;
foreach (var dim in dims)
{
    if (filename.EndsWith(dim))
    {
        ... // Выполняем нужные действия
    }
}
```